# Can Amoebae evolve into ponies?

Tags: discussion, users, humor

One and a half month ago, a new species arrived on our site: an [Ambitious Amoeba](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/using-oop-in-themes). And ambitious it was: with two questions and 66 answers, it reached 1686 reputation and is still growing. Growing so fast in fact, that it seems to have changed species and is now a [One Trick Pony](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/1986/one-trick-pony).

Since [the Biology SE proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12502/biology) is still in its infant stages, I have to ask this on our own Meta: is this a natural evolution, or is it an example of intelligent design? I just can't fit the three images on one coherent timeline:

[An ambitious amobea http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3f/Wilson1900Fig3.jpg/175px-Wilson1900Fig3.jpg](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3f/Wilson1900Fig3.jpg/175px-Wilson1900Fig3.jpg)
[A fierce WPSE user http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c22343f527e2ef06f64b0aa533ca86c5?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c22343f527e2ef06f64b0aa533ca86c5?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG)
[A one trick pony http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8e/Gracie-rhs2005.jpg/175px-Gracie-rhs2005.jpg](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8e/Gracie-rhs2005.jpg/175px-Gracie-rhs2005.jpg)

Comment: One unfortunate fallout of this comedic question is the Mr. *"Formerly Known As Ambitious Amoebae"* changed his name to *"One Trick Pony"* which left a a trail of "broken" references to "Ambitious Amoebae" in answers and comments; they now make no sense to people who don't know the history of this meta post. Anybody [anyone coming here from Google](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/search-all-stack-exchange-sites/) and then reading those question pages is likely to be very confused. FWIW.

Comment: @Mike: One Trick Pony changed his name before I created this "question", it is in fact the reason I wrote it (I was surprised to see a new name with such a high reputation). Maybe I misunderstood you, but I hope you don't think this question was the cause of the name change? And indeed, name changes can lead to hard to follow comments, but I think comments should be secondary to answers, and if interesting information is given in a comment it should be edited into the answer. (MSO is full of broken references as some of the active users there change names very often.)

Comment: Ah, I did think that but now I don't. I guess then your reason for posting the question was my same sentiment; if you have participated a lot then changing user names ends up being not so good for the other users. Glad to understand better why you posted this now.

Comment: that's ridiculous. Nobody who lands here from google cares who commented on questions, besides you two apparently. They shouldn't even care who answers/asks them.

Comment: @One Trick Pony: Sometimes it can matter, when there is a reply like `@Ambitious Amoeba: What you said is incorrect.` But these are the exceptions, and (IMO) that's why the answer they belong to should be edited to include extra information in the comments, so that, indeed, one should only read the answer to understand what's going on. BTW: I don't think changing your nick is something bad, and of course this question is just a joke, to celebrate the fact that you became such an active member in a short time. [I also did this with Mike once.](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/144)

Answer (score 5):

**I believe I've found the missing piece to your amoeba pony evolution puzzle!**

[image: Amoeba Pony]

Answer (score 3):

:)

There's no such thing as intelligent design, it's only wishful thinking

Comment: Then how do you explain Unicorns? They are clearly designed.

Comment: unicorns are the result of quantum fluctuations :)

Comment: See my comment above.